# How to implement something like this in an android application?

Tags: android, user-interface, material-design

[image: Single choise picker]

I'm looking for the right and convenient way to create this item. I spent many hours on the internet and still have not found anything like it on the android. Thank you in advance.

Comment: These could be radio buttons with custom background shapes

Comment: Or buttons inside a CardView with rounded corners

Comment: @ZaidMirza I can't flag comment as correct answer, but your comment is very helpful. I did it, thanks.

Comment: glad to help. You can post your solution as answer for others.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use Android native library i suggest [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout), with a ViewPager.

It will allow you to have one tab selected at a time, and have the animation when you slide to the next tab.

This is just an example that you can take a look at: https://android.jlelse.eu/tablayout-and-viewpager-in-your-android-app-738b8840c38a

There are also some custom libraries that will maybe give a better animation or something like that but i suggest you first try this before trying 3rd party libs.